# extracting or converting angular js page to static html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, openxml-sdk

I have tabbed angularjs application, is it possible to get the html page out of my current page which has the model variables.
     so for example i have table

```
<td>book.name<td>
```

It displays the value but the view source has only this book.name. is there a angular function to get this static html view?

so I will get

```
<td>.Net<td>
```

**Edit:** Trying to convert the html into OpenXML. Use it later to convert to different office documents. leave out certain parts add some parts etc would be easier that way in OpenXML format

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by gettin the dom element? It's possible that there's another solution

Comment: Trying to convert the html into OpenXML. Use it later to convert to different office documents. leave out certain parts add some parts etc would be easier that way in OpenXML format

Comment: Is this some kind of feature of the site that you'd like to let the users to do or something that you do yourself every now and then? The "tabbing" could be a bit of a problem if it means parts of the app aren't rendered when you want to get the html. Depends on the implementation. If it doesn't give problems though, I guess you could just do `document.body.parentElement.innerHTML`. Put that in console and it might just do the trick.